# Better way of handling 'this' in closures in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I often write Javascript code of the form:

```js
MyClass.prototype.loadData = function() {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var obj = this;
    oReq.onload = function() { obj.onDataLoaded(); }
    oReq.open("get", url, true);
    oReq.send();
}
```

The part that seems unelegant is the `var obj=this` to assign the current object to a temporary variable, (`obj`) just to be able to refer to it in the `oReq.onload` function. For all other variables besides `this`, that would not be necessary, as they are automatically part of the closure, and thus can be referred to in `onload()`. But `this` is not part of the closure and instead always (?) refers to the object that the method is bound to.

So is there a more idiomatic way of accessing the current `this` object from within a function being bound to another object than to assign `this` to a temporary variable first and then use that variable?

Comment: More idiomatic is to get rid of `this` altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler :

```
this.onload = this.onDataLoaded.bind(this);
```

Another handy solution will come with ES6, arrow functions with their lexical this binding :

```
this.onload = () => { this.onDataLoaded() }
```

(you can already use them in Firefox)

Comment: ... and maybe a compatibility note? `:)`

Comment: @VisioN I don't know. Can't we forget IE8 now ?

Comment: Every time someone asks to support IE8-, I leave a little XP end-of-life message on the end of the answer

Comment: [I would like to but seems someone still uses it...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25622121/1249581)

Comment: Yes, I know... I even recently saw a question about a problem on IE6... But I'd prefer to not lose time and precious brain cells on that unless specifically required... The same for Netscape 1.12.